# Plot a line chart in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 columns of numbers, column A i want to be the X axis of a line graph, and column B to be the Y axis. Whenever i select the range, Excel just gives me two series instead of plotting one against the other. I am obviously missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only an intermediate Excel user, but:

- make sure you choose XY chart,
- even then you might need to go into the chart's properties and assign one range to the X axis and one to the Y axis (I assume there is a better way, but I don't know it)

Comment: thanks. Its called a scatter (XY chart) for some reason. We learned in school, this was a line graph!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply pick scatter plot and you get x vs. y for the selected cells. My daughter had the same issue trying to do some homework and I finally figured it out.